# Having problems with sqlite3's path?

Tags: python

I created my first tkinter+sqlite app using lubuntu and it works fine but when I ran it on windows I kept getting a database not found error.

this is my code:

```
class App():
    ...

class Data():

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, inst=None):
        self.serverlist = []
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.inst = inst
        self.populate_serverlist()
        self.populate_attributes()
        print(self.username + self.password + self.inst)

    def populate_serverlist(self):
        ...

    def populate_attributes(self):
        ...

    def add_new_profile(self, username, password, inst):
        ...

    def get_profile(self):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def run_query(sql, data=None, receive=False):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("profile.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if data:
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
        else:
            cursor.execute(sql)

        if receive:
            return cursor.fetchall()
        else:
            conn.commit()

        conn.close()

    u/staticmethod
    def first_timeDB():
        create_table = "CREATE TABLE profile (username text, password text, inst text)"
        Data.run_query(create_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()

    if not os.path.isfile("profile.db"):
        app.data.first_timeDB()

    app.mainloop()
```

I tried replacing "profile.db" for a full path ('C:\User\Doc\profile.db') but still would not find it.

Then I also tried this tip but also didn't work, this is the modified code:

```
class Data():
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "profile.db")

    ...
    def run_query(sql, data=None, receive=False):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
```

I get an "NameError: name 'db_path' is not defined" error (even though it creates the profile.db file as per my **main** code). So anyone knows what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: ***""NameError: name 'db_path' is not defined""***: As it stands you have defined a `class variable` and want to access it like a `local variable`. Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self|Class and Instance Variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)

Comment: @stovfl Well, that's weird. I tried using 'global dp_path' inside the method but still will give the same error

Comment: ***"I tried using 'global dp_path'"***: It's not a `global` issue, have your read up and understand the given link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Turns out it has nothing to do with the path. The method 'populate_attributes()' was trying to get values from the table before it was created, as this method was being called by the class Data's **init()**.

Answer (score -1):

The DB path should be double slash `\\` or `/` when you run it on windows.